# Parsing A Text File, So That Every Line Is Stored As An Array Value

Tags: java, arrays, list, parsing, loops

Basically, I want to parse, line by line, a Text file so that every line is in it's own array value.

E.g.

```
 Hi There,
 My Name's Aiden,
 Not Really.

 Array[0] = "Hi There"
 Array[1] = "My Name's Aiden"
 Array[2] = "Not Really"
```

But all the examples I have read already just confuse me and lead me to get frustrated. Maybe it's the way I approach it.

I don't know how to go about it, a point in the right direction would be most satisfying.

Comment: I'm afraid you're not going to get much out of people here. Have you attempted to write some code yourself?

Comment: Yes, I have, but ended up in errors.

Comment: At least show us your attempt so we know where you get stuck

Comment: As @Robin said, show us your attempts in a simplified, compilable format so that we can see what the problem is and solve the *specific issue* that you are facing. At the moment, you haven't given us any clues as to what the problem might be and we don't like to give out sample code without understanding here.

Comment: Hint: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `List<String>` instead of `String[]` as arrays have fixed size, and that size is unknown *before* reading. Afterward one could make an array out of it, but to no real purpose.

For reading one has to know the encoding of the file.

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/Me/list.txt");
//Charset encoding = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
Charset encoding = Charset.defaultCharset();
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, encoding);

for (String line : lines) {
    ...
}

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
     String line = lines.get(i);
     lines.set(i, "-- " + line;
}
```